# c++ code structure into html files

Tags: c++, html

I work on unix.
I have my complete source code in unix in the form of building blocks and modules.
Like headers,sources files,make files etc.
I can copy all the files with the same directory structure to windows.
I need some tool which will convert all the source to html tags with all the links to functions,variables,classes,headers.There should be some tool to do this easily.
by this way it would be easy for debugging the code in a fast way.

Is anybody aware of such tool?

Comment: After a few seconds of thought I can kind of imagine what you're thinking about. Can you point us to a public source repository that demonstrates such an effect? It might help people point you to a solution.

Comment: I'm note sure about it, so I prefer comment than answer; I think Doxygen let you do that, but I can't remember how. - You'd probably have to use some doxygen info, though.

Answer (score 3):

The term you're probably looking for is "documentation generator".  You're specifically interested in ones that output HTML files.

[Doxygen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doxygen) is popular, but if you want a master comparison list of documentation generators Wikipedia has a summary:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_documentation_generators

Looking at the output generated by the different programs (on projects that use them) will probably inform your choice of which meets your needs.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/) to generate your documentation. In its basic form it will generate what you need but to add comments that appear in the final html you will need to use special style comments.