# Looking for a Qt open source project which is similar to Windows Paint

Tags: c++, qt, paint

I'm searching a Qt open source project for reference. Is there such a project like Windows Paint?

Comment: This site is not a search engine.

Comment: An issue complicating finding these is that most of the Qt-based apps of this nature require KDE...so searches might not turn up obvious simple examples like what @Universe wants.  (Plus don't bite the newbies, people ask for documentation generators or whatever which are much easier to find on Google and no one votes 3 closes on their question in 10 minutes, esp. if you can't find the answer w/a search engine yourself.)

Comment: Although off topic here on SO, it might be ok on http://programmers.stackexchange.com, I'll vote to close and move it there. In the mean time qt-apps.org is a good place to look for Qt programs of almost any kind. There are some in the graphics editor section here: http://qt-apps.org/index.php?xcontentmode=4224&PHPSESSID=cf4ea9ccb2cbc81b0d492c97d743c270

Comment: I don't see this hurting anything... it's a non-trivial question to answer... might be useful to someone searching later... doesn't at all belong on programmers.stackexchange.com... and see it no more off-topic than the likes of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7109504/c-code-structure-into-html-files/7109578#7109578

Comment: The question you link to is about a programming tool which is considered on topic according to the FAQ. I would not strictly consider Paint to be a programming tool so they don't match that way. The question has merit, it just doesn't fit here as well as it would on programmers.stackexchange.com. I feel that moving it will give the question a better chance of being seen and considered by people that will have good answers for it instead of just being closed.

Comment: Jeez, the only inappropriate tools here are the people closing the question.  What's being asked about is *Qt as applied to a paint program*, not the usage or application of paint itself.  It's a question about a specific C++ library, a hard one to answer since "paint" and "qt" give almost exclusively results about the `QPainter` class and draw engine stuff, and there's certainly nothing in the programmers.stackexchange FAQ that suggests this would fit there, so you're saying it pretty much can't be asked anywhere...lame: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/faq#questions

Comment: I'm apologize for asking a inappropriate question. Maybe my question is not clear or specific enough. I will do better next time. Thank @Arnold Spence for telling me the site programmers.stackexchange.com :) The site is great, I haven't known it before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What Qt gives you in the base examples is the "Scribble" sample, which is supposed to get you started:

http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/widgets-scribble.html

But if you wanted something that's going to have shape tools, color palettes, and other features then there's KolourPaint, but it is dependent on more than just Qt for both the compile-time and run-time...as it uses KDE:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KolourPaint

You might have difficulty finding a clone of MS paint written in "pure" Qt.  In part, that's because Microsoft Paint is kind of a useless program, and I always found this video rather amusing :-)

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hxx2KcPWWZg

Comment: Thank you very much, @Hostile Fork :) The "Scribble" example is enough for me now. I'm sorry I haven't find it in Qt SDK before :P The video is amazing :)

Comment: You're welcome, and welcome to StackOverflow...some Wikipedia features, a little bit of a MMORPG, and a few trigger-happy question closers :P  But it's a site that has more ups than downs, worth fighting the good fight for!